# .net core request list parameter always gets null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to send a list of object in http post request to .net core app but my list in the controller always gets null.
When I parse the json inside the code using JsonConvert it runs perfectly .
I cant find why it doesn't bind properly to the model .

My action :
`public async Task<ActionResult> FileTypes([FromBody] FileTypesRequest data)`

FileTypesRequest :

```
public class FileTypesRequest
   {
       public List<FileTypeChoice> FileTypes;
   }
```

FileTypeChoice:

```
public class FileTypeChoice
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
```

Postman request body:

```
{
    "fileTypes": [
        {
            "content": "test",
            "type": "excel"
        },
        {
            "content": "test2",
            "type": "excel"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help ?
Thanks !

Comment: Please show us the exact request that is being fired to server.

Comment: POST /FileTypes HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1000
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 199

{
    "fileTypes": [
        {
            "content": "test",
            "type": "excel"
        },
        {
            "content": "test2",
            "type": "excel"
        }
    ]
}@OrelEraki

Comment: Seems it's case issue. You are having you property in Pascal case and data you are passing in camel case.

Comment: @शेखर .NET has deserialized from camelCase to PascalCase by default for years. So it's unlikely to be a case issue, unless the poster has unknowingly configured some non-default behavior.

Comment: @Noah yes you are correct. there seems to be some other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution

```
public class FileTypesRequest
{
   public List<FileTypeChoice> FileTypes;
}
```

to

```
public class FileTypesRequest
{ 
   public List<FileTypeChoice> FileTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Made the FileTypes  from variable to property.

Answer (score 0):

#### NOT AN ANSWER JUST TRYING TO HELP DIAGNOSE

Enable HttpLogging
Using `AddHttpLogging` and `UseHttpLogging` methods in the Startup.cs file.

You should be able to see the request body in the console log.

Most time these values are null when the case doesn't match. When you add controllers to the service configure the Json to be match case. (camel or member casing)

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: This is some sound diagnostic advice. But it's not an answer...